# How can I pass jvm argument via Ant - Swing

Tags: java, swing, ant, jvm-arguments

I want to pass the JVM argument `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to my swing application using Ant script, I'm using eclipse and I'm looking for the minimum Ant script content to do this. this is my first use of ant buildfile.

Comment: do you use the ant script to build that application, or do you want to invoke the application in an ant script?

Comment: @davida. : no I'm not using ant script, and...if I undertand the second part that's what I want. not sure because this is the first time when I use ant.

Comment: Do you simply want to start the application from Eclipse, with the parameter (JVM system property) set?

Comment: No, I want that the generated app (swing gui) start with this jvm argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to build a jar file containing your application. It is however not possible to specify a run-time system property when doing so.
For an overview of JAR structure, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html - though it is possible to specify a main class of your application, it is not possible to set any parameters for it.

To set the system property to JVM upon your application start, you can do one of:

Set the property in code, e.g. in a static initialization code on your main class:

```
static {
 System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); }
```

Or, pass it as a command line parameter when starting your JAR:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourapp.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one works for me, but the first one doesn't. I put it in the main function. my program doesn't accept you syntax, I have just added `System.setProperty(...)`, but no result when I generate the runnable jar.

Comment: The code shoudl be used as static initialization of your main class (i.e. the one that contains your main method). You should not place it into `main()`, but in the body of your class. While calling `System.setProperty()` in main works as well, it might be too late if initialization of some of static fields in your class is dependent on that property - hence the static block.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [ant's java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) to launch app, then see its `<jvmarg >..` options.  You have to set `fork` to true, so that application runs under a new process with appropriate system properties set.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone is using run.xml then add this line to pass argument to jar file, `<jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>` inside the Java node.